# libGDX: How to generate SHA256?

Tags: hash, libgdx, cross-platform, sha256

How do I generate SHA256 from a String in libGDX?

It has to work on all platforms (Desktop, Android, iOS, Web), so I can't use Apache Commons Codec or any other third party library...

Any ideas?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved this by generating & handling hash values directly in my REST API and not in my libGDX application.